On-Prem DataGAteway | Custom Connector | Import a Postman Collection
I would like to create a custom connector to connect to an application (On-prem) using API and data gate way . Develop a cloud flow to use the custom connector and On-prem gateway and pass the test login user credentials in the flow and get the token . Please provide an example with steps
I created a custom connector and connected to on-prem data gateway , developed a flow by facing difficulty in passing the login user credentials and get a token
